# Legacy code error, how to fix? media_buttons

Tags: php, wordpress, legacy

I am redesigning a WordPress site from a previous version on a different server with the current WP.   I am getting a php error but don't know what it means or how to fix it.  The "solution" in the code looks to be the same code as the error:

```
Deprecated: media_buttons is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 3.5.0! Use media_buttons instead
```

I have found other legacy code I have fixed with find and replace, but don't know what to do with this one!
TIA
Jeff

Comment: I do know that in 3.5 the [`media_buttons_context`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_buttons_context/) filter was deprecated in favor of the `media_buttons` action. You might have to search your code, but it would be related to buttons in the WYSIWYG editor

Comment: You must find the actuall plugin / point in the theme that still uses this functions. Thats at least the first step. Its a bit of a process but I would download a complete copy of the website locally (using FTP) and do a search inside the "wp-content" for that "media_buttons" function... that might give us the information as to the cause of this warning...  Another way could be to turn off plugins and to see when this disappears but you might encounter other issues trying that depending on the structure of your theme... How updated is your wp installation & plugins?

Comment: BTW... this seems to be just a warning - if you see it on the frontend and don't want to deal with it right now you could just turn these notices off inside wp-config by changing "WP_DEBUG" to false...